# How to remove all instances of an HTML tag VS Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I have an HTML file that has many useless tags like empty `<p>` tags, and `<span>`'s that I want to delete. Is there any easy way to remove all `<span>`'s from my document without finding each one and deleting it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use a regex to highlight all the empty elements and then just replace them with nothing. The regex is `<[^/>][^>]*>\s*\n*<\/[^>]+>`, which includes empty tags that span multiple lines.

In VSC, when you do a search and replace (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>), make sure you have the "Use Regular Expression" option selected (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>), use the above regex, and then replace it with nothing.

Comment: This could be improved with a back-reference, see https://regex101.com/r/IgOhlr/1.  Unlikely to have a `<` in the element text but easily solved.  Also note that if there are nested empty tags you will have to run the regex replace again - to be expected really.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think that there's any package or an extension that can help you with it, however, what I personally usually do in cases like such: highlight one of the tags that I need removed, reach out to `Select all occurrences of current word` shortcut in VS Code:

- for Mac it's Cmd + F2 or fn + Cmd + F2 on the highlighted word
- for Windows its Ctrl + F2

and with Cmd + Backspace remove all lines with the highlighted tags.